# Show that the iteration $v\to\alpha\int_a^bv(x)dx+1$ converges uniformly if $|\alpha|\,(b-a)<1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

> Let $X = C[a,b]$, where $-\infty < a < b < \infty$ and $\|u\| = \max_{x \in [a,b]}|u(x)|$. Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb{R},$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
>   $$|\alpha|(b -a) < 1.$$
>   Prove that for each given $u_o \in X$, the iteration method
>   $$u_{n+1}(x) = \alpha \int_a^b\sin(u_n(y))dy + 1,$$
>   for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}, x \in [a,b]$, converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to the unique solution $u \in X$ of the integral equation
>   $$u(x) = \alpha \int_a^b\sin(u(y))dx+1, \quad x \in [a,b].$$

This is my reasoning so far. We can define an operator $A:X \to X$, by setting
$$A(u) = \alpha\int_a^b F(u(\cdot))dx + 1,$$
where the operator acts on $x$ by $A(u):[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, by
$$A(u)(x) = \alpha\int_a^b F(u(x))dx + 1,$$
and $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, by $F(\cdot) = \sin(\cdot)$. Thus,
$$A(u)(x) = \alpha\int_a^b\sin(u(x))dx + 1.$$
Does this makes sense? Now, We set the iteration to be $u_{n+1} = A(u_n)$. To show that $u_n \to u$ uniformly, it must be the case that given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $$\|u_n - u\| < \epsilon \quad \forall n \geq N, \quad \forall x\in [a,b].$$
We now have:
\begin{align*}
|u_{n+1} - u| &= \left|\alpha \int_a^b(\sin(u_n(x)) - \sin(x)) dx\right|\\ 
 &\leq |\alpha| \int_a^b(|\sin(u_n(x)) - \sin(x)|)dx\\
 &= |\alpha|(b-a)|\sin(u_n(x)) - \sin(x))|\\ 
 &\leq  |\sin(u_n(x)) - \sin(x))| \\
\end{align*}
so that 
$$\|u_{n+1} - u \| \leq |\alpha|(b-a)\max_{x\in [a,b]}|\sin(u_n(x)) - \sin(x))|\leq \max_{x\in [a,b]}|\sin(u_n(x)) - \sin(x))|.$$
I have in mind that since $|\sin(x)|  \leq 1$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that by the triangle inequality that
$$\max_{x\in [a,b]}|\sin(u_n(x)) - \sin(x))| \leq 2,$$
this means that 
$$\|u_{n+1} - u \| \leq 2,$$
I do not know how to proceed from here. any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there an error in the equation for $u(x)$?

Comment: In my homework exercise, it is written as is in the beginning.

Comment: It certainly should

Comment: I think the question is still wrong. Observe that the functions $u_n$ are constant the way you have defined them.

Comment: I will talk to my professor to see if there is something wrong and will update as soon as possible.

Comment: You already gave the proof yourself, mostly: $|u_{n+1} - u| \leqslant |\alpha|(b-a)|\sin(u_n(x)) - \sin(x))|$ for every $x$ and $|\sin(t)-\sin(s)|\leqslant|t-s|$ for every $(t,s)$, hence $|u_{n+1} - u| \leqslant |\alpha|(b-a)|u_n-u|$ with $ |\alpha|(b-a)<1$, done.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that the inequality $|\sin(t)-\sin(s)|\leqslant|t-s|$ was true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that $A$ is a contraction under the supremum norm, namely $\|A(f)-A(g)\|\le \alpha(a-b)\|f-g\|$. Therefore the iteration converges (in the sense of this norm) to the unique fixpoint of $A$. That is exactly the claim.

Comment: A is not an operator $A:X \rightarrow X$, therefore Banach's Fixed Point Theorem does not apply. Which fixed point theorem are you using?

Comment: We have recently discussed the Banach's Fixed Point Theorem, and I think that somehow it need to be applied. Maybe i am not defining the operator correctly, or there is something missing or wrong in the problem.